# How to retrieve the files uploaded in the console manually

Tags: android

I’m new in Android development and I want to develop a e-book app with pdf Files. I have uploaded the pdf Files in firebase console manually and want to retrieve the files in the app. Can anyone please help me in retrieving.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I have tried the steps in the firebase sample. But didn’t get the result. I also searched for various samples but the output is only about uploading the files in the firebase console through android app.